# Hibernate Validator not working for request body

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-validator

Please check below example and help me in it .

I need to validate productName, Description , Size and price , If am not passing any values need to get a error response with message provided in entity .

**Entity:**

```
Entity
@Table(name="products")
public class Products implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int productID;

    @NotNull(message="Name cannot be missing or empty")
    @Size(min=3, message="Name should have atleast 3 characters")
    String productName;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Please provide a description")
    String description;

    @NotNull(message = "Please provide a price")
    @Digits(integer = 10 /*precision*/, fraction = 2 /*scale*/)
    float price;

    @NotNull(message = "Size must not be empty")
    char size;

}
```

**controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveProduct" ,method =RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> saveProductController(@Valid @RequestBody Products prod) throws ProdDetailsNotFound, ProductAlreadyPresentException {
        System.out.println("Save");
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(prodServ.saveProductService(prod), HttpStatus.CREATED); 

    }
```

**ControllerAdvice:**

```
@ControllerAdvice
@RestController
public class GlobalControllerAdvice extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler{

     @Override
        protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex,
                                                                      HttpHeaders headers,
                                                                      HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {

            Map<String, Object> body = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            body.put("timestamp", new Date());
            body.put("status", status.value());

            //Get all errors
            List<String> errors = ex.getBindingResult()
                    .getFieldErrors()
                    .stream()
                    .map(x -> x.getDefaultMessage())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            body.put("errors", errors);

            return new ResponseEntity<>(body, headers, status);

        }
    }
```

**JSON Passed in Postman:**

```
{

    "productName":"aa",
    "description": ,
    "price":"200.00" ,
    "size": 

}
```

not giving an error response.

When I try below

```
{

    "productName":"aa",
    "description": "asdasd",
    "price":"200.00" ,
    "size": "L"

}
```

am getting :

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-05-23T07:51:30.905+00:00",
    "status": 400,
    "errors": [
        "Name should have atleast 3 characters"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you really using: `"description": ,` and   `"size":` for the description and size input values in the first example? You should not be able to execute this request because it constitutes malformed JSON syntax. I suspect you should be getting a `400 Bad Request` status code inside Postman, so check the return status code you are receiving.

Also check what happens if you use this input instead:

```
{
    "productName": "aa",
    "description": "",
    "price": "200.00" ,
    "size": ""
}
```

This input should give you the error message(s) you are expecting to see.

I suspect the first request example does not get processed at all due to a 400 status code, meaning it never even gets to the back end, hence no message.

Also, rather than using 
`@RequestMapping(value = "/saveProduct" ,method =RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")`,

try this:

```
@PostMapping({"/saveProduct"})
```

It's a shorthand version of the above and makes the code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add @Validated above the controller.
Like the example of a more modern way to write Post mapping:

```
public interface EmployeeController {
    ResponseEntity<Employee> register(@Valid Employee employee);
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/employee")
@Validated
public class EmployeeControllerImpl implements EmployeeController {

        @PostMapping(path = "/register",
                consumes = "application/json",
                produces = "application/json"
        )
        @Override
        public ResponseEntity<Employee> register(@RequestBody Employee employee) {
            Employee registeredEmployee = service.register(employee);
            return ResponseEntity.status(201).body(registeredEmployee);
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Team, I found the issue. issue in sending JSON DATA.